# Google dataflow write data to CloudSQL postgres | java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a ETL pipeline using google dataflow to write data to CloudSQL postgres database. But I am facing error connecting to the cloud sql instance.

```
String jdbcConURL = "jdbc:postgresql://google/<db-name>?cloudSqlInstance=<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory";
pipeline
    .apply(
        BigQueryIO.read()
        .fromQuery("select * from <big-query-table>")
        .usingStandardSql()
        .withoutValidation()
    )
    .apply(JdbcIO.<TableRow>write()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(
        JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
        .create("org.postgresql.Driver", jdbcConURL)
        .withUsername("<username>")
        .withPassword("<password>")
    )
    .withStatement("insert into <sql-table-name> values(?,?,?)")
```

I get the following error of unknown host.

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.

> java.net.UnknownHostException: google at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220) at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:61) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:121) ... 45 more

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to the dependency version in `pom.xml`. Changing to the latest version of `org.postgresql` resolved this.

old version

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version> 
</dependency>
```

new version

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>42.6.0</version> 
</dependency>
```